# How to have a border and a bottom border on a button

Tags: html, css

I need to achieve [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHPCo.jpg).

Here is my code so far:

```css
.button {
  border-color: red;
  border-radius: 8px
}

.button::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Click me </button>
```

The problem is that the width covers 100% of the screen, and I need the width of the button; I can't give a specific width to this button because it will receive dynamic text.

Comment: As we can see when your code is put into a snippet, the code you supplied doesn't reproduce the issue you describe in your question. You should update your question with something more closely resembling your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be like on picture:

```css
.button
{
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.4em 0.8em 0.2em 0.8em;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.button::after
{
  content: '';
  background-color:red;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  left: -1.3em;
  bottom: -1em;
  width: calc(100% + 2.6em);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Tab Tile</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap the button in a div with `display: inline-block` to prevent it going full-width and relative positioning so it can contain an absolutely positioned element inside and from the looks of your image some padding on that element as well to create some space between the button and the line below. Then make your :after pseudo element absolutely positioned and give it `width: 100%`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  padding: .75rem .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  border: 3px solid #EF544F;
  padding: .5rem;
  color: #EF544F;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.2rem
}

button::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #EF544F;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 999px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try min-width

```
  .button::after{
         content: '';
         background-color:red;
         display: inline-block;
         width: auto;
         height: 3px;
         min-width:100px;
   }
```